# python subprocess: FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run a second file. I copied everything from a video and I still get this error.

```
from subprocess import call

class CallCourses(object):

    def __init__(self, path=r'file2.py'):
        self.path = path

    def call_module(self):
        call(["Python3", f"{self.path}"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = CallCourses()
    c.call_module()

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I also tried setting the path to the absolute path and put it inside a raw string:

`````
r'C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\MyProject\file.py'
````but I get the same error
`````

Comment: The `Python3` may be what's don't being found. Please add a complete backtrace of the error to your question.

Comment: `f"{self.path}"` is just a really obscure way to write `self.path` (or strictly speaking `str(self.path)`, but in this case`self.path` is already a `str`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Info] 'Python3' isn't default for windows. Try to use : 'py' or 'python'

/!\ Please give us all of TracBack error /!\

Comment: I should switch to that linux already :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First, you can change **python3** to **python** or **py** because it isn't default in Windows. **python3** works in linux.

You can try to use pathlib library to get the correct path.

```
from pathlib import Path
current_path = Path.cwd()
```

current_path shows the path of your file, then you change **self.path** to this:

```
self.path = current_path / path
```